# Autocorrelation function of a Wiener process & Poisson process.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, correlation

[image]

---

Can anyone possibly explain step 3 and 4 in this solution?

Comment: @Clarinetist : you meant $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]]$

Comment: @leonbloy Ah yes, thank you